# Failed to inflate packfile Visual Studio Error

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013, inflate

im trying to pull the current branch of a project on github.

When i click sync in Visual Studios Team explorer, I receive the following error:

```
    "An error occurred. Detailed message: Failed to inflate packfile"
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Im using visual studio 2013 with update 4 by the way

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue where my local code repository was on a network share. To fix this I used the GIT Windows client to CLONE the repository on the network drive first.  Than in VS2013 I selected the LOCAL option within Team Explorer.

This error can happened if you don't launch VS2013 as admin.